# Printing cuts off part of the page with redirected printers in terminal services

Tags: windows-server-2008, service, terminal, printer, windows

I have looked this issue up extensively and have i have came across a hot fix, KB959442. Where i am having an issue is trying to apply this hotfix. It says this is for Windows XP SP3 machines but i can not run the hotfix on the machines because when i get the downloaded hot fix it is a .msu file and i have read that only Windows Vista, Windows 7 and Server 2008 machines can execute this particular file. I have also tried running this on the Windows 2008 Terminal Server but when i do it give tells me this file is not compatible with this machine. I have made sure that i downloaded the correct hotfix also. Any ideas would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Microsoft usually provides free support for their hot fixes if they do not work correctly.

Comment: Where can you get free support? The support options i have seen cost $$

Answer (score 1):

In the KB you referenced:

Note To resolve this problem on a Windows XP SP3-based computer, install hotfix kb957070 that is described in the following Microsoft Knowledge Base article: 
957070  (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/957070/ ) When a user offers a Remote Assistance invitation to an expert user who...

Answer (score 0):

Like Joeqwerty mentioned, there is an additional KB needed to install for XP SP3.  Additionally I would look at your print drivers.  Try out different drivers on the client (make sure they're loaded on the TS as well).  I had a similar issue that I resolved by changing the driver from PS to PCL (or something similar).  Regardless, try loading different drivers.  You may not even need that KB to fix the issue.